# How to compute the characteristic variety of a perverse sheaf occurring in the Springer correspondence?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

In particular, how to do for the first nontrivial case when the representation of the Weyl group is the sign representation? As far as I know, one can probably use the Fourier transform and compute for the trivial representation instead. But is there a direct way to compute it that may work for all the representations of W?